# c++ passing by reference : error: no matching function for call

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, parameter-passing

I have this code :

```
bool Port::add_app_from_wlist(App* a){
 stringstream namesurn;
 string name, surname;
 namesurn << a->get_name();
 namesurn >> name >> surname;
 return add_application(a->get_id(),name,surname,a->arrived_at_port_by(),a->arrived_by(),a->is_luxury_class());
}
```

I get this error :

> air_classes.cpp:153:
> error: no matching function for call
> to `Port::add_application(int,
> std::string&, std::string&, time_t,
> time_t, bool)'
>
> air_classes.cpp:98:
> note: candidates are: bool
> Port::add_application(int,
> std::string, std::string, std::string,
> time_t, time_t, bool)

I do not understand where this string& comes from in the error - nor how can I amend it - help please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `add_application` accepts 3 strings, but you specify only 2 of them in your call.

Comment: Thanks -well - I think I must delete my account now :ashamed:

Comment: @user: I remember myself making the mistake like this many times (and being unable to find what the problem is without somebody's help) :-) Two pairs of eyes is certainly better than one.

Answer (score 3):

The references simply come from the compiler not finding a suitable function to call which matches the values that you are trying to pass, and guessing what the function signature might look like.

Compare with the listed candidate which accepts three, not two, string parameters.